# aspnetForm.target ='_blank'; is not working in asp.net 4

Tags: asp.net

I am using following code but it's not working. But in 3.5 it is working fine.
If any one can explain the reason and how can use this code effective in asp.net 4?

`OnClientClick="aspnetForm.target ='_blank';"`

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" 
         onclick="Button1_Click" OnClientClick='aspnetForm.target="_blank";' />
```

code behind:

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
    }
```

Comment: explain your question in detail and share your code also

Answer (score 2):

I think the new Predictable ClientID setting in asp.net 4 cause this problem.

If you set controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion back to 3.5 and ClientId to AutoID it will work again.

But the best solution would be to do this with javascript.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function openWin(url) {
        var wnd = window.open(url, 'title', 'width=600,height=400,toolbar=1');
        wnd.focus();
    }
</script>
```

ASP.NET button

```
<asp:Button ID="openButton" runat="server" Text="Button"           
    onclick="btnOpenPop_Click" />
```

Code behind

```
protected void btnOpenPop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string url = "http://www.yoururl.com";
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "OpenWin", "<script>openWin('" + url + "')</script>");
}
```

Comment: In asp.net there is `ClientIDMode ="Static"` have you seen that?